# In Drupal 8 , what the usage and function for the .post_update.php?

Tags: php, drupal-8

I saw the file of `docroot/core/modules/menu_link_content/menu_link_content.post_update.php` in my project. But I can not figure out what the destination for this file. Could any one can explain for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MODULE.post_update.php` file contains the `hook_post_update_NAME` functions. The purpose of these hook functions is to update data, such as entities. These updates are executed after all `hook_update_N()` implementations, which are executed when you run `/update.php`

#### References:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_post_update_NAME/8.2.x